# Why is my op-amp getting hot?

Tags: operational-amplifier, thermal

I am using a LM4562 dual op-amp (in SOIC-8) as a level-shift and attenuation stage between an audio amplifier and an ADC. The circuit works fine, with the expected gain and shift, but the op-amp gets hot (68°C). The board is sitting on the bench in free air with no enclosure.

[image]

The amplifier isn't oscillating, and is at the same temperature with or without a 1kHz 1Vpp input signal.

The datasheet states a maximum "Total quiescent current", (which I guess means both amps summed together), of 12mA. 12mA * 30V = 360mW. The thermal resistance junction-case is 35°C/W. With Ta=25°C, that would put the case temperature at 25 + (35*0.36) = 38°C.

Are my thermal assumptions invalid?

Comment: For the SOIC package, datasheet says junction to ambient is 145*C/W, giving a nominal 52*C above ambient rise.

Comment: note this may be an acceptable temperature for the op-amp even though it is too hot for your finger. It's probably a good idea to add a heatsink anyway, but 68 degrees isn't a dangerous temperature for electronics.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Junction-to-ambient (JA), not junction-to-case (JC) because the heat is being sinked to ambient, not the case.

Junction-to-case is used when you are connecting a heatsink directly to the case, and when you do that you the need to also account for the heatsink's thermal resistance.

[image: Extract from datasheet showing thermal resistance data]

Image source: [TI LM4562 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4562.pdf)

Comment: Aah, that makes sense, thanks. I was looking for a number that would tell me the temperature of the case, not the junction, since that is something I can measure.

I guess to get the case temperature I can subtract 35C/W from 145C/W?

Comment: @jeffmakes Yeah. Like a voltage divider hooked up to a current source. Temperature is voltage, mW is current. Your junction is the current source output  pushing 360mW of current through two series resistors. The total divider resistance is 145C/W, The resistor closest to the case is 35C/W and the resistor closest to 0V is 145C/W-35C/W. Ambient is GND, and you can offset it by the ambient temperature to get the actual temperature or leave it at zero to get the temperature rise.